# How to turn off output from shutdown hooks in gradle boot tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

You can generate a project from start.spring.io to this issue from https://start.spring.io/starter.zip?type=gradle-project&language=java&bootVersion=2.2.5.RELEASE&baseDir=demo&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.8&dependencies=h2,data-jpa,web

I have a multi-module springBoot application built with gradle, there are a bunch of SpringBoot integration tests. When I do a build I end up with some output from the SpringBoot shutdown to the console as shown below. How do I turn this output off?

```
± |master ↑1 {1} S:3 U:10 ✗| → ./gradlew build

> Task :core:test
2020-02-01 11:20:33.529  INFO 24114 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-02-01 11:20:33.531  INFO 24114 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-02-01 11:20:33.538  INFO 24114 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

> Task :email:test
2020-02-01 11:20:43.820  INFO 24150 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-02-01 11:20:43.820  INFO 24150 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-02-01 11:20:43.822  INFO 24150 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-02-01 11:20:43.822  INFO 24150 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-02-01 11:20:43.830  INFO 24150 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-02-01 11:20:43.830  INFO 24150 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.

> Task :security:test
2020-02-01 11:20:54.941  INFO 24188 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-02-01 11:20:54.944  INFO 24188 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-02-01 11:20:54.952  INFO 24188 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 46s
57 actionable tasks: 54 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

For reference an application created from start.spring.io with gradle produces no output on the screen

```
./gradlew build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 779ms
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
```

Instead the output is placed in `build/reports/`

In my case I have NOT made any changes to the logging configuration that comes with boot. There is no logback.xml, or changes to the application.yml for logging levels. I am expecting that gradle is capturing the system out and system error and sending them to the `build/reports/` but some outputs seems to be escaping to system out.

Comment: Adjusting the logging level for those packages or classes to below `INFO` (or removing completely).

Comment: I don't see any of the output from boot and there is a a lot of it. I don't understand why gradle is printing the last few lines of output from boot sometimes 3 lines sometimes 6 lines.

Comment: It's printing 3 lines when there's 1 datasource and 6 lines when there's 2 datasources.

Comment: I think those are because there are multiple spring application contexts due to context from the spring framework. My understanding of gradle is  that all output should not be sent to the console. Which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: Those are `INFO` level log lines. They originate from the shutdown hooks as you see, and they end up where ever the logging is configured. I suppose in theory the messages might end up in a different place than intended, due to logging configuration changing and the hooks being executed asynchronously afterwards. So it would default those lines to the console, as the previous config was unloaded. Maybe.

Comment: @ams Did you find a proper solution?

Comment: @user3180909 nope I did not find an answer.

Comment: Can you add your test class, and your main application class too please? And any relevant application.properties/yml assoicated with datasource config?

Comment: I am with @Kayman - hook could be executed after classes are already offloaded including logging or logging config...

Comment: I have made  no changes to the default out of the box boot logging configurations. And keep in mind that boot prints a bunch of lines at INFO level when the app starting up. Why is only a bit of the output shown?

Comment: What do you mean by "only a bit of the output"? What would you like your output to look like? You could just disable all of the logs by setting the log level to `ERROR` or `WARNING`

Comment: standard output from a spring boot application such as the spring boot logo, and info about what libraries have been auto configured for example 2020-03-04 08:15:43.887  INFO 38279 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.498 seconds (JVM running for 0.721)

Comment: Can you add your log logback.xml / application.properties for your test package? Those messages might be disabled by default for tests while the JDBC log level is still on info smh.

Comment: It could be that the shutdown hooks happen when the Gradle test worker processes are turned down after their output redirection is teared down. That might be worth a gradle/gradle issue to open the discussion.

Comment: Ideally spring boot is shutdown in your tests without having to rely on jvm shutdown hooks, that would be a spring issue.

Comment: >"...reference (an) application created from start.spring.io with gradle produces no output..." - cannot reproduce/confirm: for me the output is quite vivid and starts with "gradle(w) download..." `extShutdownHook` logging is specific to "spring-data ..." (so dependant from *what* you pick @start.spring.io) - and can be configured (for tagged case) via 1. [gradle logging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) options  or via 2. [spring-boot logging configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-logging) ...

Comment: You can generate a project from start.spring.io to reproduce this issue from https://start.spring.io/starter.zip?type=gradle-project&language=java&bootVersion=2.2.5.RELEASE&baseDir=demo&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.8&dependencies=h2,data-jpa,web

Comment: i *have* console/logging output, also from your sample @ams. My (shortened) console (gitBash-windows7) output : `$ ./gradlew build

Welcome to Gradle 6.0.1! ...(bunch of text)
...
> Task :test
2020-03-04 20:40:23.133  INFO 11736 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : ...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 59s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed` and the last part seems only sort of a "tail", since in progress the ouput changes. Why behaves it differently for us?

Comment: ok, on my "2nd build" I can (though seeing "flash messages" in progress) by the end see: `$ ./gradlew build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date` ...but this I'm "quite sure" because tests didn't run! ('cause code didn't change..) When code changes or `clean build`, then again: test output including spring-data logging.

Comment: All those proposals of changing log levels are just workarounds. A real fix would be on gradle side to also capture shutdown hook output IMO. I found [this github issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12423) matching your question. Let's see if they can fix or provide a solution.

Answer (score 4):

@eskatos is right. The logging manager is teared down after the test case is executed before the shutting down the worker process. All the shutdown hooks are executed when the worker process is shutdown and are redirected back to console.

As these messages are generated by spring boot the best place would be to filter the shutdown messages using the logback test configuration xml.

Something like logback-test.xml inside src/test/resources

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
                <expression>return event.getThreadName().contains("ShutdownHook");</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

build.gradle

```
testCompile 'org.codehaus.janino:janino'
```

Answer (score 3):

One can disable the output with [`TestLoggingContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html) `testLogging.showStandardStreams = false` **or** decide what to log `onOutput` of a [`Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) task, in order to control the stdout/stderr of the test JVM:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {

    // show standard out and standard error of the test JVM on the console
    // can be used to disable the console output:
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    // listen to standard out and standard error of the test JVM
    // can be used to make the logging optional:
    onOutput { descriptor, event ->
        logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message)
    }
}
```

These streams are `TestLogEvent` [`STANDARD_OUT`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/logging/TestLogEvent.html#STANDARD_OUT) & [`STANDARD_ERROR`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/logging/TestLogEvent.html#STANDARD_ERROR), which are coming from the JVM. When one can determine an `event.message` containing `extShutdownHook`, one can skip the logging.

Comment: see You can generate a project from start.spring.io to this issue from https://start.spring.io/starter.zip?type=gradle-project&language=java&bootVersion=2.2.5.RELEASE&baseDir=demo&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.8&dependencies=h2,data-jpa,web to reproduce the issue

Comment: It is probably a non-issue, because `INFO` is the default logging level for Spring; one can set other log-levels, eg. `logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE` as environmental variable.

Comment: I believe shutdown hook logs are generated outside of test task. Could you update your answer to show how one can filter shutdown hook messages ? I think the best place to filter these messages is where they are generated that is in spring boot anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I could hide the spring-data specific test-logging (based on [this spring-starter](https://start.spring.io/starter.zip?type=gradle-project&language=java&bootVersion=2.2.5.RELEASE&baseDir=demo&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.8&dependencies=h2,data-jpa,web))
by adding the follwoing `application.properties` to src/**test**/resources:

```
logging.level.root=ERROR
```

`logging.level.org.springframework` won't have effect on e.g. `com.zaxxer.hikari` logger, but you have [flexible options](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-logging) here.

(`root=ERROR` is like the "sledge hammer approach").

(`src/main/resources` is also possible but has effect not only at test but also at application runtime)
(`application.properties` is only one of [*many* possible "locations"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) for this property...see also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)

With this I get a "silent" gradle output, also on a `clean build`:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has a quiet mode.

`./gradlew build -q`

But you still need information about the tests. you can use jacoco and sonarqube. It worked for me [here](https://github.com/shermende/spring-cloud-stream-kafka/blob/master/build.gradle#L44) and [here](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=shermende_spring-cloud-stream-kafka).

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Boot 2.5 Update**

This solution does not work anymore.
See this GitHub issue for details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28108

---

In recent versions, Spring Boot has a property to shut down the logging system before exiting. Add the following line to your configuration:

`src/test/resources/application.yaml`

```
logging:
  register-shutdown-hook: true
```

`src/test/resources/application.properties`

```
logging.register-shutdown-hook=true
```

---

The property definition and documentation can be found in the Spring Boot repository on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json

```
{
  "name": "logging.register-shutdown-hook",
  "type": "java.lang.Boolean",
  "description": "Register a shutdown hook for the logging system when it is initialized. Disabled automatically when deployed as a war file.",
  "sourceType": "org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener",
  "defaultValue": true
}
```

It seems like the shutdown hook is not registered by default when running tests.